# Instagram iPhone application questions

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm developing an application like Instagram for learning iOS programming.

My application is a client for an images hosting website where users can share picture from own iPhone.

I have few questions:

- When you open Instagram and you're not logged in you don't see the tabbar with five buttons. You see a black bar with two button for login and signup. How can I hide the tabbar and show a bar like that (probably it's a standard bar, right) if the user is not logged in?
- Relying on your opinion, what is the role of the application's model? (should I use a model or you hint me to use only view controllers?) The first thing that comes in my mind as "data model" it's the images array. This array will refresh when a user click on the "Refresh posts" button. There's also "Popular images", so I think it's another array separated from the global images array. Should it inserted in the model, right? I ask this because I would to organize in a good way my application for model/controllers/view pattern.

If you give me some hints I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Present the modal view controller without animation, like siuying said. The modal view controller can hold its own instance of `UITabBarController`, so you can have a tab bar there that has a login tab and signup tab or similar. Behind, in the real, main view controller, have your normal five or however you're doing it. That way, once the user is signed in, you can just dismiss the modal view controller. Easy
2. I don't entirely understand your question here. Load the images on their own thread when the tab is clicked on for speed/resource use. I don't see how a model comes into this. Can you clarify this? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The point is an user logged in and an anonymous user must see the same tabbarcontroller (with the same view controllers) except for the tabbar on the bottom, that should present only two button "login" and "signup". Maybe I can do this hiding the tabbar and present a UIToolbar. About the second question, I ask what is the role of a model in this application. I'm a newbie iOS developer and I didn't never use models, I did all of my things in view controllers, but I know it isn't a good way of programming.

Comment: From the user's point of view, it would look like the same tab bar controller, especially if you used animations to fade between the two. Or just take your existing tab bar controller and add in new tab bar items once logged in, while removing the login and signup items. Harder, but it would use the same tab bar controller if that's what you're bent on doing. My way, it wouldn't have to look different. The user would see the same one from their point of view.

Comment: It sounds like you're confused about models vs views. Of course you will use view controllers, or at least UIViews to display information, etc. The model aspect of iOS programming is a way to insert information into that view. It's more of a concept than a tangible item. Your model could exist in its own class files (.h and/or .m) that contained method calls to load the images and do whatever else you need to with them. Then just #import your class files and call the methods from your view controllers. Or, just include those methods in the view controllers. It's really up to you. Look up MVC.

Comment: Thank you dude. You've clarified me some concepts about models. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Does my answer and comments answer your original question? Remember to accept it if it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You may modally present a view controller (without animation) on launch, when user is not logged in. You may then dismiss the modal view controller after login finished successfully.
2. Model here usually not only refers to the data (images array), but the logic and behavior of the app. For instance, download images from server should be implemented in model. You may want to check  [MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I append details in my @Dylan G comment.